# How to position a div to stay above footer on a specific page through jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a 2 columns page layout and I want to add a div to stay just above the footer on a specific page.

How can this be done through jQuery?

Thanks!
Vic

Comment: CSS sounds like a better option, although some code will be needed for a definitive answer.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this through CSS. What I think is that if I can find the position of the #footer I can add the wanted div above it but this can be done through jQ only.

Comment: It's hard for anyone to know what you want without a more detailed question

Answer (score 0):

If your `DIV`s are `absolute` or `fixed` position this will work:

HTML:

```
<div id="footer"></div>
<div id="aboveFooter"></div>
```

JS:

```
var $footer = $('#footer');
var $aboveFooter = $('#aboveFooter');
$aboveFooter.css('top', ($footer.css('top') + $aboveFooter.height()) + 'px');
```

If the footer is not an absolute coordinate then you need to use relative CSS.

Comment: the footer is not positioned absolute / fixed. Can you give more details how to do it using relative positioning? I don't think is possible through CSS but I will give it a try if you say so.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for a CSS solution...

```
<style type="text/css">
footer { 
    position: relative;
}
div#above {
    position: absolute;
    height: 30px;
    top: -30px;
}
</style>

body<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<footer>
    footer
    <div id="above">above</div>
</footer>
```

If you can't edit the `div` directly into the footer's html, like in the above, then you will need just need to append it with jquery, the CSS will still do its job.

`$('footer').append('<div id="above">above</div>');`

Comment: this is not gonna do the job because I want to add the div to a specific page and the footer is dynamic added to each page...

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to do without jquery. Just add the following code in your footer.

```
<footer class="footer bg-white" data-background-color="black">
    <div style="position: absolute; right: 20px; top: -90px">
        <img src="{{asset('assets/img/ict_div.png')}}" alt="" style="width: 150px">
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      footer data
    </div>
</footer>
```

If you still need to use jquery, you can write this code:

```
<div id="above">
    <img ....>
</div>

---------
jquery:
$('#above').attr('style','visibility: hidden');
or,
$('#above').attr('style','top: -90px');
```

can be done based on your need.